# Merge unique lists in neo4j query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

Hi I have a usecase where I need to extract the `user ids` of

- all the people liked by user a
- all the people disliked by user a
- id of the user itself

In my case

```
13 - :likes    -> 18
13 - :likes    -> 19
13 - :dislikes -> 20
```

So I want output as `[13,18,19,20]`

This is the query I have come up with

```
MATCH (a:Person {id: "13"})
MATCH (a)-[:LIKES]->(l:Person)
MATCH (b)-[:DISLIKES]->(d:Person)
RETURN (
    collect(distinct(toInteger(a.id))) 
    + 
    collect(distinct(toInteger(l.id)))
    + 
    collect(distinct(toInteger(d.id)))
);
```

Is there a better or straight forward way of achieving this? I am new to the world of neo4j.

Answer (score 1):

A simpler version and more straightforward version is probably

```
MATCH (a:Person {id: "13"})-[:LIKES|DISLIKES*0..1]->(b:Person)
RETURN collect(distinct(toInteger(b.id)));
```

So are are traversing both relationships in a single match. The path can be oz zero length to also capture the original node and handle cases where it has no relationships.